# C programming. Using execl and pthread

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm having a problem in the combined use of execl() and pthread.

My idea is quite simple: write a daemon that in certain situation starts an external process (a separate executable with respect to the daemon itself) and wait for the return value of that process. Moreover I want to have the possibility to start multiple instances of the same process at the same time.

The part of my code to handle multiple threads:

```
...
for (c_thread=0,i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
        /* Start actions before start threads */
        for (j=c_thread;j<c_thread+config.max_threads;j++)
                         Before_Process(act[act_index[j]].measID);

       /* Now create threads */
        for (c=0,j=c_thread;j<c_thread+config.max_threads;j++)
                {
                        Print_Log(LOG_DEBUG,"Create tread n. %d, measurementID=%s",c,act[act_index[j]].measID);
                        if ((ret=pthread_create(&pth[c],NULL,Start_Process_Thread,(void *) &act[act_index[j]].measID)))
                                {
                                        Print_Log(LOG_ERR,"Error in creating thread (errorcode: %d)",ret);
                                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                                }
                c++;
                }
        /* Joint threads */
        for (j=0;j<config.max_threads;j++)
                {
                        if ((ret=pthread_join(pth[j], (void**) &r_value[j])))
                        {
                                Print_Log(LOG_ERR,"Error in joint thread (errorcode: %d)",ret);
                                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                        }
                }
       /* Perform actions after the thread */
        for (j=0;j<config.max_threads;j++)
                {
                        status=*(int*) r_value[j];
                        Print_Log(LOG_DEBUG,"Joint tread n. %d. Return value=%d",j,status);
                       After_Process(act[act_index[c_thread+j]].measID,status);

                }

        c_thread += config.max_threads;
        }
...
```

And the function Start_Process_Thread:

```
void *Start_Process_Thread(void *arg)
{

int *ret;
char *measID;
measID=(char*)arg;

if (!(ret=malloc(sizeof(int))))
        {
        Print_Log(LOG_ERR, "allocation memory failed, code=%d (%s)",
                              errno, strerror(errno) );
                      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

*ret=Start_Process(measID);
pthread_exit(ret);
}


int Start_Process(char *measID)
{
...
  pipe(pfd);
  pid=fork();
  if (!pid)
    {
      signal(SIGALRM,Timeout);
      alarm(config.timeout_process);
      flag=0;
      /*
         Start the Process.
      */
          ret=execl(config.pre_processor,buff_list[TokCount-1],config.db_name,measID,(char *) 0);
      if (ret==-1)
        {
          alarm(0);
          flag=1;
          Print_Log(LOG_ERR,"Cannot run script %s, code=%d (%s)",config.process, errno, strerror(errno));
        }
      alarm(0);
      close(1);
      close(pfd[0]);
      dup2(pfd[1],1);
      write(1,&flag,sizeof(int));
    }
  else
    {
      wait(&status);
      close(pfd[1]);
      read(pfd[0],&flag,sizeof(int));
      close(pfd[0]);
      if (!flag)
        {
          if (WIFEXITED(status))
            {
              if (!(return_value=WEXITSTATUS(status)))
                {
                  /*
                     Process gives no errors.
                  */
                  Print_Log(LOG_INFO, "Processing of measurementID=%s ended succesfully!",measID);
                }
              else
                {
                  /*
                     Process gives errors.
                  */
                  Print_Log(LOG_WARNING,"Processor failed for measurementID=%s, code=%d",measID, return_value);
                }
            }
          else
            {
              /*
                 Timeout for Process
              */
              Print_Log( LOG_WARNING,"Timeout occurred in  processing measurementID=%s",measID);
              return_value=255;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The above code works fine from technical point of view but I have a problem somewhere in handling the return values of the different instances of the called external process. In particular it happens that the return value associated to a certain instance is attributed to a different one randomly. 
For example suppose 4 different instances of the external process are called with the arguments meas1, meas2, meas3 and meas4 respectively and suppose that meas1, meas2 and meas3 are successfully processed and that for meas4 the process fails. In situation like that my code mix up the return vales giving success for meas1, meas3, and meas4 and failure for meas2 or success for meas1, meas2, meas4 and failure for meas3.

Any idea on why this can happens?

Any help is really welcome.

Thank you in advance for your attention.

Answer (score 3):

When any thread in a process executes `wait()`, it gets the information about any of the process's dead children — not necessarily about the last child started by the thread that is doing the waiting.

You are going to need to think about:

1. Capturing the PID of the process that died (it is returned by `wait()`, but you ignore that).
2. Having a single thread designated as the 'disposer of corpses' (a thread that does nothing but `wait()` and record and report on deaths in the family of child processes).
3. A data structure that allows the threads that start processes to record that they are interested in the status of the child when it dies.  Presumably, the child should wait on a suitable condition once a child starts so that it is not consuming CPU time doing nothing useful.
4. The 'disposer of corpses' thread handles notifications of the appropriate other thread whenever it collects a corpse.
5. Worry about timeouts on the processes, and killing children who run wild for too long.

It's a morbid business at times...

Comment: Thanks! I have solved the problem just using waitpid() function instead of wait().